# Change html with php on responsive layout

Tags: php, css, responsive-design

I have a question regarding responsive layout. Lets say I have a css file with completely different styles once the browser size is lower than "xx". In my example the css code is as follows:

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), only screen and (max-width: 960px)
```

Now my question: 
When I view my website (http://web3.server.e-astro.de - its german...) on a mobile and I click on a link, to a subpage with information on it, I always have the menu first on top and have to scroll down to get to the real content. The solution for that would be to give the content link a name like `"<a name="start"></a>` and link directly to that. So I don´t always have the menu on top.
But I want that to occur only on the mobile version and not on the browser version.

So I´m looking for a php code like this:

```
<a href="site.php<?php IF ON MOBILE STYLESHEET VERSION echo '#start'; ELSE DO NOTHING ?>">
```

Does anybody know how to archieve this? I hope I made myself clear...

Thank you!!

Comment: PHP only has access to the user agent string, but there's no guarantee that the UA has honestly identified itself.

Comment: Do you know a better solution then to archieve my question? :)

Comment: Redesign your menu so it doesn't take up so much space?  Yes, it should be finger friendly, but it doesn't have to be visible by default.  Consider controlling its display with a toggle via JS instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS is not for altering code and it used just for presentation. To solve your issue you'll need to detect the user device with PHP and if it's mobile - you can output the mobile stuff.

For example with this little class - [Mobile Detect](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect)

```
include 'Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect();

if ($detect->isMobile()) {
    echo '#start';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would be best to consider mobile navigation in your design; one approach which I like is to have the menu to load in a collapsed format on a mobile, which then expands when tapped. This will allow the navigation to be accessible, without obstructing the rest of the content on the page.

[Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/starter-template.html) has a really great collapsible navigation for mobile in the responsive component of the framework.

Comment: This is not a bad way to go, definitely... But it would be my last solution to change my layout alltogether. Well, not alltogether but still it takes work. And the site has to go life next Tuesday :) I´d rather have a solution like requested if possible. But thanks anyway!!